# How can we add / remove the object values with respect to entries with hashmap?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

```
 List<ServiceModel> serviceList = [
    ServiceModel(id: "12", name: "Repair", subServiceList: [
      SubServiceModel(name: "Toilet Repair", id: "123"),
      SubServiceModel(name: "SafetyTank Repair", id: "456"),
      SubServiceModel(name: "Roof Repair", id: "789")
    ]),
    ServiceModel(id: "13", name: "Fixing", subServiceList: [
      SubServiceModel(name: "Roof fix", id: "222"),
      SubServiceModel(name: "pipe fix", id: "111")
    ]),
  ];
```

I have data like above.. What i need to do is make a multiple selection with respect to servicemodel and also can remove  any from the subservicelist..So that i can have only specific selected data with respect to the  specific serviemodel..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to make one intance of ServiceModel is different from others:

```
class ServiceModel{
   final String id;
   final String name;

   ServiceModel({required this.name, required this.id });       

   @override
   bool operator ==(other) => other.hashCode == hashCode && other is ServiceModel;
   @override
   int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

It will give following:

```
var service1 = ServiceModel(id:"1", name:"service1");
var service2 = ServiceModel(id:"2", name:"service2");
var service3 = ServiceModel(id:"1", name:"service3")
//false
print(service1 == service2);
//true, because their ids are same
print(service1 == service3);
```

Then let's make a ServiceModel tree entity.Each serviceModel will have subServices( children ). Why tree? It will give you flexibility that you can make nested ServiceModel of not only 2 but whatever levels you want.
Updating the code above:

```
  class ServiceModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<ServiceModel> subServices;

  ServiceModel(
      {required this.name,
      required this.id,
      this.subServices = const [],});

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) =>
      other.hashCode == hashCode && other is ServiceModel;
  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

Now modifying your code build servicesList:

```
    List<ServiceModel> serviceList = [
    ServiceModel(id: "12", name: "Repair", subServices: [
      ServiceModel(name: "Toilet Repair", id: "123"),
      ServiceModel(name: "SafetyTank Repair", id: "456"),
      ServiceModel(name: "Roof Repair", id: "789")
    ]),
    ServiceModel(id: "13", name: "Fixing", subServices: [
      ServiceModel(name: "Roof fix", id: "222"),
      ServiceModel(name: "pipe fix", id: "111")
    ]),
  ];
```

Then how you can build list of selected ServiceModels? Easy:

```
    List<ServiceModel> selectedServices = [];
  List<ServiceModel> serviceList = [
    ServiceModel(id: "12", name: "Repair", subServices: [
      ServiceModel(name: "Toilet Repair", id: "123"),
      ServiceModel(name: "SafetyTank Repair", id: "456"),
      ServiceModel(name: "Roof Repair", id: "789")
    ]),
    ServiceModel(id: "13", name: "Fixing", subServices: [
      ServiceModel(name: "Roof fix", id: "222"),
      ServiceModel(name: "pipe fix", id: "111")
    ]),
  ];
  //you may add whatever service, each of them has unique hashCode according to id
  selectedServices.add(serviceList.first.subServices.first);
  //true
  print(selectedServices
      .contains(ServiceModel(name: "Toilet Repair", id: "123")));
```